# How do I draw line (slanting line)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, line-drawing

How do I draw a non-orthogonal line?

If we have an orthogonal line it's pretty easy:

Consider X1 = 100, Y1 = 80; And X2=100, Y2 = 185;

So we have something like this for this line.

```
for(nRow = Y1; nRow < Y2; nRow++)
{
   for(nCol = X1; nCol < X2; nCol++)
   {
     nPixPos = nRow*nEffectiveWidth+nCol*3;

     Image[nPixPos] = 0 ; /// Image -> unsigned char * (BUFFER) || 0 -> Black COLOR
     Image[nPixPos+1] = 0 ;
     Image[nPixPos+2] = 0 ;
  }
}
```

If I want to draw a non-orthogonal line such as:

X1 = 100 , Y1 = 80 and X2 = 115 , Y2 = 185

How would I go about constructing a loop to draw this line?

Comment: If you are using some graphics software, you should either add a tag (if it exists) or explain in the question. C++ by doesn't know anything about drawing.

Comment: We'll need some more information than just the code you have there, what are you using to draw the lines? What is 'Image' and what does the value 0 represent in it?

Comment: I don't know, I figured it was pretty obvious from context that he was looking for a general line drawing algorithm and didn't really understand how to ask the question...  Also I'm going to guess that the 0 represents either color or some value that turns that pixel or tile off...

Comment: I hope this questions helps you guys to understand..Thanks @OmnipotentEntity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few algorithms to choose from I suggest [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) if you don't want anti-aliasing and [Xiaolin-Wu's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) if you do.